# ImportError: cannot import name 'CLIENT_ID' from 'credentials'

Tags: python, spotipy

I was running spotify_discography.py from https://github.com/itsmaximelau/spotify-discography, using VSCode

```
    import spotipy
    import time
    from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth, SpotifyClientCredentials
    from credentials import CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET,REDIRECT_URI
    
    ### REMEMBER TO CHANGE VARIABLES IN CREDENTIALS.PY, SEE GITHUB FOR DETAILS ###
    
    # This is the scope for Spotfy Auth, change for the following values if you want the generated playlist to be public
    #scope = "playlist-modify-public"
    #public_playlist = True
    
    scope = "playlist-modify-private"
    public_playlist = False
    
    # Spotipy object
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id="30b1607fe77f41ac891c14d5be7f02c7",client_secret="7c9986b751994256a1577a06842f51b4",redirect_uri="http://localhost:8888/callback",scope=scope))
    
    # Current user id
    spotify_user_id = sp.me()['id']
    
    # Creates a playlist for authentified user and returns playlist ID, 
    def create_playlist(name):
        playlist = sp.user_playlist_create(spotify_user_id, name=name, public=public_playlist)
        playlist_id = playlist["id"]
        return playlist_id
    
    # Adds a song list to a playlist
    def add_to_playlist(song_id,playlist_id):
        sp.user_playlist_add_tracks(spotify_user_id,playlist_id,song_id)
    
    # Return a list of albums ID for a selected artist
    def search_artist_albums(artist):
        albums = []
        albums_id = []
        album = sp.artist_albums(search_artist(artist)["id"])
        albums.extend(album['items'])
        while album['next']:
            album = sp.next(album)
            albums.extend(album['items'])
        unique = set()
        
        for album in albums:
            if album["album_group"] in ("single", "album"):
                name = album['name'].lower()
                if name not in unique:
                    unique.add(name)
                    albums_id.append(album["id"])
        return albums_id
    
    # Return a list of songs ID for a selected album
    def search_album_songs(album_id):
        songs = []
        song = sp.album_tracks(album_id)
        songs.extend(song['items'])
        while song['next']:
            song = sp.next(song)
            songs.extend(song['items'])
        return songs
    
    # Return an artist ID using Spotify search function
    def search_artist(artist):
        artist_search = sp.search(q='artist:' + artist, type='artist')
        return artist_search["artists"]["items"][0]
    
    # Main script - creates a playlist for selected artist
    def create_artist_discography(artist):
        playlist_id = create_playlist(artist + " - Discography")
        albums = search_artist_albums(artist)
        print("Found every albums from the artist (" + str(len(albums)) + ").")
        
        # Search for albums
        unique_song_id = []
        for album in albums:
            songs = search_album_songs(album)
            for song in songs:
                song_id = song["id"]
                if song_id not in unique_song_id:
                    unique_song_id.append(song_id)
        print("Found every songs from the artist (" + str(len(unique_song_id)) + ").")
        time.sleep(5)
        
        # Split requests in 100 songs per request
        amount_of_songs = len(unique_song_id)
        amount_of_last_request = amount_of_songs % 100
        amount_of_full_requests = int((amount_of_songs - amount_of_last_request)/100)
        
        #100 song requests
        for x in range(amount_of_full_requests):
            song_list = unique_song_id[(x*100):(x*100 + 100)]
            add_to_playlist(song_list,playlist_id)
            print("Adding " + str(len(song_list)) + " songs to the playlist.")
            time.sleep(5)
        
        #Leftover request
        if amount_of_last_request != 0:
            song_list = unique_song_id[-amount_of_last_request:]
            add_to_playlist(song_list,playlist_id)
            print("Adding " + str(len(song_list)) + " songs to the playlist.")
        print("Playlist for " + artist + " is done.")
    
    def main():
        create_artist_discography(input("Enter an artist : "))
    
    main()
```

And then this appeared:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Gigabyte\Downloads\spotify-discography-main\spotify-discography-main\spotify_discography.py", line 4, in <module>
    from credentials import CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET,REDIRECT_URI
ImportError: cannot import name 'CLIENT_ID' from 'credentials' (C:\Users\Gigabyte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\credentials\__init__.py)
```

I've followed every single instruction there is. All the imports and from(s) are already green-colored, except for "CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET,REDIRECT_URI". What should I do to tackle this issue and get the spotify_discography.py file to work?

Comment: Did you do as the comment says `### REMEMBER TO CHANGE VARIABLES IN CREDENTIALS.PY`?

Comment: I couldn't seem to find credentials.py besides the one in "C:\Users\Gigabyte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\telegram\passport", even after opening that .py file - I'm clueless on which part should I modify. @JohnGordon

Comment: The author has added the credential file to their gitignore so you can't see it on the project but you will need to create a file that stores the credentials you get from spotify and place it in the same folder as this project. Similar to the file in this commit: https://github.com/itsmaximelau/spotify-discography/commit/93f59b49890d93df876374358e28723631ca0978